# Who declined my flag?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

I see that my flag was declined, with a **custom** reason:

> [image]

I suspect it is Dom who had declined this, since he/she is also a mod on Music SE - he/she has been quite active all over me lately in an arguably suspicious way:

1. He/she has given me an account suspension on Music SE for a year - currently still in effect
2. Has been quite strict over the nature of my posts and its activity
3. Has constantly been refusing to lift my suspension early when I asked him/her to do so, as he/she is the mod who is responsible for this
4. The writing style in the flag rejection message looks just like Dom's

Which mod declined my flag here then?

Comment: I don't know what the flag was about, but considering your custom reason, you need to know that even you are Christian, the community is not, so some rules that apply within your religion don't necessarily apply here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did decline the flag, but which moderator handles which flag is rather irrelevant. This would have been rejected by any mod for the reasons pointed out in this meta post: [Why was my edit reverted?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/why-was-my-edit-reverted).

This SE is rather small so only a handful of users will be taking actions at a time so mods need to step in more. I also tend to be one of the more active mods, so when issues come up I do tend to see them first.

---

For the record for 1 and 3, I was not the only mod involved in that on Music SE and please stop trying to bring suspension you have on Music SE up here. We are two separate SEs and actions on one don't translate to actions on another. You've been warned about this via mod message already. Constantly bringing this up has no effect on the situation there and is disruptive to this SE.