# What can I do to improve my flagging quality?

Tags: support, flagging

> [image]

I just got banned from flagging posts for a week, so I am uploading a screenshot of all my flags that were declined in the past seven days.

Here are my flags:

1. Rude or abusive
2. Can you mark this as community wiki, please?
3. Very low quality
4. Very low quality
5. Not an answer
6. Off-topic
7. No longer needed

I would like you to explain why the seven flags were mass-declined (I think they are naive/valid flags), and give some tips for avoiding flag bans, please.

Comment: You should said first what you don't understand in the decline reasons that were provided. Most of them are quite explanatory. Have you read what people said?

Comment: @Brahadeesh I raised a custom (in need of mod intervention) flag with the typed-in text "very low quality".

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya, again you were trying to hack the system, which you were explicitly told to not do. If you can't flag as VLQ, please don't custom flag with VLQ, custom flags are not for VLQ.

Comment: And as I said earlier, with a screen shot, we cannot see what was all about, you should give links to posts, what were your intentions, why did you flag. So we can help you and tell why your thinking was wrong.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya, for example, I see you flagged one of my posts. It's okay, but why didn't you try to talk to me first in the comments of the said post? Maybe we could figure this out before you flag it and I could explain to you why there is nothing rude/abusive. This would avoid a declined flag...

Comment: @Bebs if I cannot VLQ it, then what flag can I use?  NAA?  Where are getting that info from?  I actually **can.**  I am not trying to hack the system.

Comment: I can't read your mind, I don't know what were your intentions and you should tell us. What do you think was wrong in these posts? Could it be resolved by simple comments? Could it be resolved by editing?

Comment: @Bebs the custom flag is meant to be used when the flag reason is not in the list.  I am trying to flag something as VLQ, AND the post purely meets the VLQ status, but the VLQ flag option is not available.  Then I can raise a custom flag with the text VLQ, which becomes convenient.  So I can't raise a custom flag with the VLQ text **if** the VLQ option already **is** available.

Comment: In general, mods look at the reasons separately, so if the wrong flag reason is chosen, they will EXTREMELY likely decline it (but edit / close / delete the post).  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105395/447378) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You flagged "rude or abusive" [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/when-did-musicians-started-to-call-each-other-motherfucker-in-a-friendly-meaning)

The question has been around for more than two years, and two very active members have participated in it, so you really think they would miss something rude or offensive? Flag was not necessary here when you could just comment Chris's post or mine if there was something you want to talk about.

Also, in october you were informed that "*Due to the nature of this site and lyrical expression in certain genres, language will not always be professional when it comes to lyrics and there may be some foul language on the site.*" by Dom [here](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/532/3260).

**This is an occurrence where you are warned of something once, but you don't listen.**

2. You custom-flagged "Can you mark this as community wiki, please?" [this answser](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/10187/3260).

This could have been said in comments directly to the answerer. Mods have nothing to do.

3. You custom-flagged "VLQ" [this answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/8682/3260).

As you know, the VLQ flag is available only for seven days after the post. So it is not necessary to custom-flag an old post with this reason.

Even if the post is very short, it has an artist, a song and a year, so it could be an answer. You are free to ask for clarifications in the comments, to downvote, to edit it yourself of you want.

4. You custom-flagged "VLQ" [this answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7615/3260).

Same as 3.

5. You flagged "NAA" [this answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/2281/3260).

You might disagree with the answer, but it is still an answer. You are free to ask for clarifications, to downvote if you want, but from what I read, user tries to explain the difference between one word and the other.

6. You flagged off-topic [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/249/should-i-store-my-vinyl-records-side-by-side-or-in-piles).

The question is on-topic. As music fans we want to preserve our music enjoyment as much as possible, so we need to take care of our discs. There is nothing wrong here.

7. You flagged "No longer needed" a comment in [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/are-londonderry-air-danny-boy-and-you-raise-me-up-the-same-song).

I don't know what comment you flagged, and for what reason so I can't help you.

Comment: I'm not trying to hack the system.  I can't raise a custom flag "VLQ" ONLY when the VLQ option is already available.

Comment: @Brahadeesh but although it is more than a week old, its quality is still very low - the quality of the question/answer is **so** low - it is written something like this: an6uj7655fsfefsfevervfweegmaikasakuranomiyahdhdhdhduduehheududhjdudhehcudnh.  Then what would you do?

Comment: @Brahadeesh - **I am NOT trying to abuse the system.  Raising a custom VLQ flag when there is no VLQ option is NOT abusing the system.**

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya, in the case of "*an6uj7655fsfefsfevervfweegmaikasakuranomiyahdhdhdhduduehheududhjdudhehcudnh*", this is **not a answer**. Simple.

Comment: Spam or abusive would actually be better for that flag Bebs, but @MaikaSakuranomiya please listen to feedback. This is your final warning, we cannot continue to tell you the same things over and over again. You know what's expected of you and you yourself have contributed many commends that needed flagging, one just from the past 24 hours.

Comment: @Dom well, there is a VLQ post, but the VLQ flag is hidden.  Then which flag do you want me to use instead, other than rude/abusive or spam?

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya Not everything needs a flag, just vote them down if you don't think they are quality answers or edit. Voting is one of the core controls of quality on an SE site.